# Automate Microsoft Forms filling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, microsoft-forms

I have a Microsoft form which I want to automate, as I'm planning to create a chrome extension for filing the form periodically daily
Form have only two fields,
one is a text field

[image]

and second is a rating control with stars

[image]

For text field it is straight forward i can use `document.getElementById('name').value='name'` but for the stars it bit tricky as their is no button or event which i can fire

following is the HTML for stars

```
<div
  class="rateit margin-left office-form-theme-primary-foreground rateit-font"
  data-rateit-icon=""
  data-rateit-iconforempty=""
  data-rateit-mode="font"
  data-rateit-marginleft="4"
  data-rateit-marginright="4"
  data-rateit-starwidth="24"
  data-rateit-max="5"
  data-rateit-step="1"
  data-rateit-resetable="false"
  data-rateit-ispreset="true"
  style="font-size: 24px;"
  title="2 Stars"
  data-rateit-value="2"
>
  <button
    id="rateit-reset-5"
    type="button"
    data-role="none"
    class="rateit-reset"
    aria-label="reset rating"
    aria-controls="rateit-range-5"
    style="float: left; display: none;"
  >
    <span></span>
  </button>
  <div
    id="rateit-range-5"
    class="rateit-range"
    tabindex="0"
    role="slider"
    aria-owns="rateit-reset-5"
    aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="5"
    aria-valuenow="2"
    aria-labelledby="question15-title question15-required question15-questiontype l5"
  >
    <div class="rateit-empty">
      <span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="rateit-selected" style="width: 64px; display: flex;">
      <span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span // tried to trigger a click on this via JS , but no luck
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="rateit-hover" style="width: 0px; display: none;">
      <span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span
      ><span style="margin: 0px 4px;"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried updating `.rateit> data-rateit-value` & `.rateit-range> aria-valuenow` but no luck
Also tried by triggering click event on the spans which generate the stars but no luck

So is there any other way via which I can trigger the click and update the value

Comment: The only thing you actually have to trigger is the actual request and not the visual part. Just check how the request is sent and rebuild it, without any HTML. Unless you wish to keep the visual representation of course. Spontaneously it looks like `data-rateit-value` is what you need to change.